# Can I assign a getter function to a variable in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, getter

I can do

```
function yea ():int {
...
}
var cool:Function=yea;
```

I don't know how to do something like

```
function get wat ():int {
...
}
var mmmh:Function=wat; // this (tries to) assign the wat returned value
```

Comment: You can't, if you explain what is your purpose perhaps someone would give you a workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only way I know is capturing getter/setter references from inside of them with `arguments.callee`. But that's a rather weird thing to do. :)

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class GetterTest extends Sprite
    {
        private var getterRef:Function;
        private var setterRef:Function;

        private var testValue:int = 0;

        public function GetterTest()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
        }

        private function onMouseDown(event:Event):void
        {
            if (getterRef != null) {
                setterRef(getTimer());
                trace("references: test = ", getterRef());
            } else {
                test = getTimer();
                trace("direct: test = ", test);
            }
        }

        private function get test():int
        {
            trace("TEST! getter");
            getterRef = arguments.callee;           
            return testValue;
        }
        private function set test(value:int):void
        {           
            trace("TEST! setter");
            setterRef = arguments.callee;
            testValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

While the above works, I think the correct answer to your question is "don't". :)

Answer (score 0):

you could save the name of the getter as a string `var fn:String = "wat"` and then use it later to retrieve the return value of the method with `myObjectFromClass[fn]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is that you are trying to accomplish.

If you just want to keep a reference to the getter, you could just wrap it in a closure function.

```
var mmh:Function = function():int { return wat; };
```